# How is the program printing 'Hello world!' without a print statement and without using the words 'Hello world!'?

Tags: python, lambda, printing, logic

This code doesn't use the print() statement to print, also it is printing 'Hello world!' without actually using the words belonging to the phrase.

```
    (lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____, ______, _______, ________:
    getattr(
        __import__(True.__class__.__name__[_] + [].__class__.__name__[__]),
        ().__class__.__eq__.__class__.__name__[:__] +
        ().__iter__().__class__.__name__[_:][_____:________]
    )(
        _, (lambda _, __, ___: _(_, __, ___))(
            lambda _, __, ___:
                bytes([___ % __]) + _(_, __, ___ // __) if ___ else
                (lambda: _).__code__.co_lnotab,
            _ << ________,
            (((_____ << ____) + _) << ((___ << _____) - ___)) + (((((___ << __)
            - _) << ___) + _) << ((_____ << ____) + (_ << _))) + (((_______ <<
            __) - _) << (((((_ << ___) + _)) << ___) + (_ << _))) + (((_______
            << ___) + _) << ((_ << ______) + _)) + (((_______ << ____) - _) <<
            ((_______ << ___))) + (((_ << ____) - _) << ((((___ << __) + _) <<
            __) - _)) - (_______ << ((((___ << __) - _) << __) + _)) + (_______
            << (((((_ << ___) + _)) << __))) - ((((((_ << ___) + _)) << __) +
            _) << ((((___ << __) + _) << _))) + (((_______ << __) - _) <<
            (((((_ << ___) + _)) << _))) + (((___ << ___) + _) << ((_____ <<
            _))) + (_____ << ______) + (_ << ___)
        )
    )
)(
    *(lambda _, __, ___: _(_, __, ___))(
        (lambda _, __, ___:
            [__(___[(lambda: _).__code__.co_nlocals])] +
            _(_, __, ___[(lambda _: _).__code__.co_nlocals:]) if ___ else []
        ),
        lambda _: _.__code__.co_argcount,
        (
            lambda _: _,
            lambda _, __: _,
            lambda _, __, ___: _,
            lambda _, __, ___, ____: _,
            lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____: _,
            lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____, ______: _,
            lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____, ______, _______: _,
            lambda _, __, ___, ____, _____, ______, _______, ________: _
        )
    )
)
```

Can someone explain how the code works and the logic behind the code.

Answer (score 0):

What a cursed code you've found.

Interesting parts:

- these "<<" are left shift operators a.k.a. multiplying stuff by 2^shifted bits;
- that bytes command is most likely receiving an ASCII array built the with cursed parenthesis and left shifts (which are building each and every character of the printed string);
- those underlines are just unnamed variables;
- I'm not completely sure that is the case, but that getattr call seems to be the source of return/print;

Lessons learned:

- you shouldn't use lambda for that.